# php datetime->diff is calculating wrong amount of hours (3 too much)

Tags: php, datetime

I've got the following DateTime object in php:

```
[start1] => DateTime Object ( 
    [date] => 2012-05-21 12:59:59
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)

[end1] => DateTime Object ( 
    [date] => 2012-05-21 22:36:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

and the result of:

```
$time->end1->diff($time->start1
```

is:

```
DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 0 [h] => 12 [i] => 36 [s] => 2 [invert] => 1 [days] => 0 )
```

Why do I get an period of 12 hours and not 9?

Comment: What about the seconds? Shouldn't it be 1 instead of 2? Maybe it has to do something with the timezone type? Try changing that value and see what happens.

Comment: Your code got chopped off. Please post the complete line beginning `$time->end1->diff($time->start1`

Comment: Try `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');` before running the diff.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); didn't worked. And there is nothing chopped of. Only the bracket is missing and the seconds are also ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution...Before doing the diff I do a sub() on the start1 object. Now I've seen why my result is false... Here is the answer but I REALLY don't why this is happening.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php#101175

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this may in fact be what you do to create the two DateTime objects BUT I figured I would put what worked for me to see if perhaps it would help you out.

To create the two objects I did:

```
$start1 = new DateTime('2012-05-21 12:59:59', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$end1   = new DateTime('2012-05-21 22:36:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
```

And printing out the two objects and the diff:

```
print_r($end1->diff($start1));
```

I got:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2012-05-21 12:59:59
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2012-05-21 22:36:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 9
    [i] => 36
    [s] => 1
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 0
)
```

I see that both of our outputs for the start1 and end1 objects is the same, but my diff reflects the correct 9 hour difference. Perhaps there's something wonky about how you create the DateTime object in your version of PHP?